# Endomorphisms of a monoidal functor

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, monoidal-categories, hopf-algebras

Let $k$ be a field and $\mathcal{C}$ be a finite $k$-linear abelian monoidal category, and let $F:\mathcal{C}\to\text{Vec}$ be a monoidal functor from $\mathcal{C}$ to the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces with the usual monoidal structure.

Let $\operatorname{End}(F)$ denote endomorphisms of $F$ as a natural transformation.  Now everything I've read (I'm especially looking at [Etingof's notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-769-topics-in-lie-theory-tensor-categories-spring-2009/lecture-notes/) now) studies this when $F$ is faithful and exact, in which case $\operatorname{End}(F)$ is a bialgebra, and $\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent to the category of finite-dimensional $H$-modules.

However I happen to be interested in a functor which is neither faithful nor exact.  My question is whether or not $\operatorname{End}(F)$ is still bialgebra?

It seems to me it would but I'm concerned I'm making a mistake.  But my reasoning is that $\operatorname{End}(F)$ has a natural multiplication given by composition of natural transformations and that the coproduct is given (as in the case of a faithful exact functor) by composing the isomorphism $\operatorname{End}(F\otimes F)\cong\operatorname{End}(F)\otimes_k\operatorname{End}(F)$ with the map $\alpha:\operatorname{End}(F)\to\operatorname{End}(F\otimes F)$ by the following diagram:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
F(X\otimes Y) @>{\eta_{X\otimes Y}}>> F(X\otimes Y)\\
@VVV @VVV\\
F(X)\otimes F(Y) @>{\alpha(\eta_{X\otimes Y})}>> F(X)\otimes F(Y)
\end{CD}

where $\eta\in\operatorname{End}(F)$.  Am I making a mistake somewhere?  Or do people generally only care about the exact and faithful case because they want to construct an equivalence of categories?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1539627) could be of interest for you. Moreover, you may find an (in)formal treatment of the general case in Majid, *Foundations of Quantum Group Theory*, section 9.4.

If your category $\mathcal{C}$ has finitely many objects, then you have $\mathsf{End}(F\otimes F)\cong \mathsf{End}(F)\otimes \mathsf{End}(F)$ for sure and your argument is exactly the one described by Majid. However, in general you only have a morphism $\mathsf{End}(F)\otimes \mathsf{End}(F) \to \mathsf{End}(F\otimes F)$. This is one of the reasons why people work in the dual case of coalgebras: $\mathsf{Coend}(F)$ satisfies $\mathsf{Coend}(F\otimes F)\cong \mathsf{Coend}(F)\otimes \mathsf{Coend}(F)$ independently on te number of objects of your category and, in general, I believe it is much better behaved (see, for example: Schauenburg, *Tannaka duality for arbitrary Hopf algebras*; Pareigis, *Lecture notes on Quantum Groups*; Street, *Quantum groups, a path to current algebra*).

Comment: In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4480469/isomorphism-between-operatornameendf-otimes-f-and-operatornameendf/4481318?noredirect=1#comment9402043_4481318) Fosco gave a proof of $\operatorname{End}(F\otimes F)\cong\operatorname{End}(F)\otimes \operatorname{End}(F)$, where he did not need $F$ to be exact nor faithful.