# Isomorphism between $\operatorname{End}(F\otimes F)$ and $\operatorname{End}(F)\otimes \operatorname{End}(F)$, where F is an exact faithful functor.

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products, abelian-categories, monoidal-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a finite $k$-linear abelian category, and $\operatorname{Vec}$ be the category of finite dimensional vector spaces over $k$. Let $F_1,\ F_2:\ \mathcal{C}\rightarrow \operatorname{Vec}$ be two $k$-linear exact faithful functors. Then $F_1\otimes F_2$: $\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\operatorname{Vec}$ is a functor, sending $(X,Y)$ to $F(X)\otimes_kF(Y)$ and $(f,g)$ to $f\otimes g$.

We denote $\operatorname{End}(F)$ as the algebra of natural transformations from $F$ to $F$. To understand the coalgebra structure of $\operatorname{End}(F)$ (when $\mathcal{C}$ is tensor catgeory), an important step is understanding the follow isomorphism:

\begin{align}
\Phi:\operatorname{End}(F_1)\otimes\operatorname{End}(F_2)&\longrightarrow\operatorname{End}(F_1\otimes F_2)\\
\alpha\otimes\beta&\longmapsto \Phi(\alpha\otimes\beta)_{(X,Y)}\!=\!\alpha_X\otimes\beta_Y\!\!: F_1(X)\otimes F_2(Y)\rightarrow F_1(X)\otimes F_2(Y)
\end{align}

It is easy to show that $\Phi$ is a well-defined linear map.(and an algebra map when $F_1=F_2$)

My question is: **how to prove that $\Phi$ is isomorphic?** I cannot do both injectivity and surjectivity.

Comment: I am sorry if anyone think my question is same as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1526738/algebra-of-endomorphisms-of-a-functor). Because that question was 6 years ago and didn't get a correct answer, I think I would better ask one more time.

Comment: The answer from fosco is very impressive. I learned tools and languages he uses from his book *The co/end construction*. However, it did not require $\mathcal{C}$ to be finite, and $F$ to be exact and faithful, which is much stronger than Etingof's viewpoint. I dont know what causes this difference.

Comment: I would appreciate if anyone can give some explaination about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you find a flaw in this argument?

**Fact 0.** $\hom(V,W)\cong V^\lor\otimes W$ ($V^\lor$=the dual of $V$).

**Fact 1.** $A \otimes-$ (tensoring with $A$) is a continuous functor, because it has $A^\lor\otimes-$ (tensoring with the dual of $A$) as left adjoint:
$$ \hom(X,A\otimes Y)\cong X^\lor\otimes A^{\lor\lor}\otimes Y\cong \hom(A^\lor \otimes X,Y)$$

**Fact 2.** For functors $H,K : {\cal C}\to Vect$,
$$ Nat(H,K) \cong \int_X Vect(HX,KX)$$
so in particular $End(F)\cong \int_XVect(FX,FX)$.

---

But now:
$$\begin{align*}
End(F)\otimes End(G) &\cong \int_X Vect(FX,FX)\otimes \int_YVect(GY,GY) \tag{fact2}\\
&\cong\int_X\int_Y\Big(Vect(FX,FX)\otimes Vect(GY,GY)\Big)\tag{fact1}\\
&\cong\int_X\int_Y(FX)^\lor\otimes FX\otimes (GY)^\lor \otimes GY\tag{fact0}\\
&\cong\int_X\int_Y(FX)^\lor\otimes (GY)^\lor\otimes FX \otimes GY\tag{sym-$\otimes$}\\
&\cong\int_X\int_Y(FX \otimes GY)^\lor\otimes FX \otimes GY\tag{$\lor$-$\otimes$}\\
&\cong\int_{XY}(FX \otimes GY)^\lor\otimes FX \otimes GY\tag{Fubini}\\
&\cong\int_{XY}Vect(FX \otimes GY, FX \otimes GY)\tag{fact0}\\
&\cong End(F\otimes G)\tag{fact2}\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am not familiar with the language you use. I will learn it and read your answer after that!

Comment: Now I understand this proof, which based on the fact that End(F) is a particular kind of end. It is amazing to use such a highly abstract argument to prove this! However, I still have a question: we require $\mathcal{C}$ to be finite abelian, and $F$ to be exact and faithful. How do you use this conditions?

Comment: Probably the assumption that $\cal C$ has finite dimensional hom-spaces is used implicitly; but in this proof I see no restriction on $F,G$ being exact or faithful...